# Сопоставление ключей и значений в таблице

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, структуры-данных

Имеется таблица с десятками столбцов.
Первая строка - заголовки, т.е. ключи.
Для каждой строки мне нужно сопоставить ключи из первой строки с **заполненным** значением из итерируемой.

То есть, из:

```
name|age|job    |color|height
Ivan|21 |teacher|red  | 180
Petr|19 |       |white| 190
```

хочу получить:

```
{name:Ivan, age:21, job:teacher,  color:red, height:180}, 
{name:Petr, age:19, color:white, height:190}
```

Мне абсолютно непонятно, как привязать строку ключей к строкам значений, учитывая индексы.

Comment: dict(zip(1st_line, cur_line))

Comment: Вообще-то таблица с заголовками и разнотипными данными - это типичный DataFrame. А вы как ее храните? И как собрались обрабатывать  в дальнейшем? Для DataFrame вопросы типа вашего решаются автоматом - в данном случае методом to_dict(). Подумайте.

Comment: csv.dictreader модуль встроенный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=",")
res = [{k:v for k,v in x.items() if not pd.isna(v)} for x in df.to_dict(orient="records")]
```

---

результат:

```
In [25]: res
Out[25]:
[{'name': 'Ivan', 'age': 21, 'job': 'teacher', 'color': 'red', 'height': 180},
 {'name': 'Petr', 'age': 19, 'color': 'white', 'height': 190}]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Пора плотно засесть за pandas)